# Table cell content does not set on center

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dingbat, multido, array}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.1cm, right=0cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} & Md. &&\rule{0cm}{0.8cm}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\multido{}{2}
{
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.20cm}|p{5cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
SL & Name & Room No & Intention\\
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 30}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to horizontally center align the cell text. The content is put on the down side of the cell. How can I put theme to center of the cell?

I tried

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{|M{0.20cm}|p{5cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
```

not solved.

Comment: you are forcing extra height but no extra depth with `\rule{0cm}{0.8cm}` so the baseline is lower in the cell than usual. You can use the optional argument of `\rule` to give extra depth as well. The table would look odd if you really vertically centred so that the baselines of digits did not match the baseline of text unless the letters used were exactly same height as the digits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, this solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You can write this as answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I post a answer based on your comment. If you post this as a answer I will delete my answer, because this answer actually yours.

Comment: No feel free to accept your answer I am not that desperate for the green tick:-)

Answer (score 1):

Changes in comparison to your MWE (Minimal Workking Example) are in code marked by `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1pt]{geometry} % <---
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{multido}  % <---
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline\arabic{theyflines} & Md. & &  } % <---

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\multido{}{2}
{
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{0.45\linewidth}{|p{1em}|X|c|c|}
    \hline
SL & Name & Room No & Intention 
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 29}{\aline}\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\hfill  % <---
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dingbat, multido, array}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.1cm, right=0cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} & Md. &&\rule[-0.25cm]{0cm}{0.8cm}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\multido{}{2}
{
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.20cm}|p{5cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
SL & Name & Room No & Intention\\
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 30}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
}
\end{document}
```

You can use a *raise* optional parameter of [rule](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts). The text appeared on the baseline. So, for horizontal alignment you can down the box created for the `\rule{0cm}{0.8cm}` command.

[image]